# Check existance of a file to unlock app

Tags: android

I wish to create a file on my device somewhere (I don't mind where or what the file contains, my only concern is the name of the file), then have my app look for the existence of that file. The idea is to have a mechanism to secretly unlock some features of my app to anyone I tell about the file.

My only problem is that I have never written any code to read/write files outside of my own app's space before, so I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone give me some pointers.

Comment: The easiest would be to put it somewhere in the "external storage". [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: Ok, but what method do I call to check for the existence of that file?

Comment: Just use standard Java `File`s: `File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mysecretfolder");
      File file = new File(folder, "secretfile.txt");
      file.exists()`

Comment: This is easy to implement but note that anybody decompiling your app will be able to find this feature in code unless you obfuscate it significantly. This is more common than you might think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use File.exists() method to determine whether the file exists or not.

```
  File testfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator ,
                "myfile");
        if (testfile.exists()) {
            //file exists. enable your features
        }
```